# How to select a value from dropdown using serenity screen play

Tags: angularjs, xpath, serenity-bdd

I have a web page and from where I am trying to to select xpath from a drop down box which don't have any value by default.

```
<select id="country" class="multi ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-touched" ng-options="country as country.description for country in vm.countries" ng-change="vm.getDestinations()" ng-model="vm.country" style="">
<option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
<option label="Germany" value="object:589">Germany</option>
<option label="Austria" value="object:590">Austria</option>
<option label="Belgium" value="object:591">Belgium</option>
```

I have tried using Select.selectByVisibleText() but still not getting. I can find the country field but not able to select a particular country:

```
public Target selectCountry = Target.the("select country").located(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"app-container\"]/div[1]/span[3]/select[1]"));
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Am not sure what you want.

Comment: I want to select a country "Germany" in my automated test but getting the exception "net.serenitybdd.core.exceptions.SerenityManagedException: The following error occurred: Cannot locate element with text: 'Germany'"

Comment: I am using the chromedriver and getting the error: net.serenitybdd.core.exceptions.SerenityManagedException: The following error occurred: Expected enabled element was not enabled

Answer (score 0):

I am able to select the country now. It was not a serenity issue. I was getting to this page after doing some actions on the previous page. Actualy I had 2 separate "When" steps for actions on the previous page and current page. When I merged them in single "When" step then it has started selecting the country from the dropdown on the current page. I don't know why it has not worked with separate steps.

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit (extends) PageObject class to utilize pre defined select class methods such as selectByVisibleText, selectByValue and selectByIndex.

```
@FindBy(id="country")
WebElementFacade dropDown_Country

public void selectDropDownValues(){
   dropDown_Country.selectByVisibleText("Germany");
}
```

This can be called using Task like

```
actor.attemptsTo(Click.on(selectDropDownValues()));
```